# Filter by metadata in image store plugin

Tags: wordpress, image, plugins, store

I need to make one small change in the plugin http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/image-store

It is possible to make a filter to display photos based on a filter for metadata?

I think that the change should be made in the image file-store_inc\store.php

In my case I need to display only photos that have metadata credit == 000

How can I change the code for this?

Thank you!

I have tried to do this:

$metadata = get_post_meta($img_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );

$metacredit = $metadata['image_meta']['credit'];

apply_filters( ($metacredit == '0000'), $data );

//filter data close imag tag
return $output .= apply_filters( 'ims_image_tag', '', $data, $img_id, $size, $enc, $metacredit );

...but not work.

Comment: Research for `apply_filters` inside that plugin file. I saw plenty of them, much probably there's one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you Brasofilo, I tried but I can not do it ...

Comment: Can you show what you tried? You can [edit] the question and add new information to it.

Comment: in the support forum of the plugin I have responded in this way:    This is not possible by using the settings. Modifications can be made by using the plugin’s hooks.

Take a look at this hooks:
ims_pre_get_images
ims_get_gallery_images

Comment: [Read the following](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/) to understand how hooks work. And also [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web).

Comment: Brasofilo i have this code but i do not know how to change it and where to put it: Example

// apply action
function action_ims_get_gallery_images( $ImStore, $posts_per_page, $offset ) {
 //run action here
}
add_action('ims_get_gallery_images', 'action_ims_get_gallery_images');

Comment: Check the links I've provided, it should be enough to put you many steps ahead. After reading them, try something on your own and **update** the Question with your attempts. It'd be much more easier to help this way.

Comment: I have tried to do this:    $metadata = get_post_meta($img_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true ); 
   $metacredit = $metadata['image_meta']['credit']; 
   
   apply_filters( ($metacredit == 'GRUPPO 163'), $data );  ...but not work..

Comment: Gianny, ***[edit]*** your Question to improve it. Reading code in comments is a pain...